# Deploying java azure function via maven and getting ssl handshake error

Tags: java, maven, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy a java jar via mvn azure-functions:deploy command to Azure. previously I have had no issues with deploying this function. However I am now getting the following error:

> [INFO] Auth type: AZURE_CLI
> Default subscription: *********************a1cb3e)
> Username: *********.com
> [INFO] Subscription: *************************
> [INFO] Reflections took 271 ms to scan 5 urls, producing 25 keys and 747 values
> [WARNING] [f259252a, L:/********* - R:management.azure.com/****************] The connection observed an error
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException (ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1907)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap (ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:834)
> at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap (SSLEngine.java:509)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap (SslHandler.java:1041)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData (SslHandler.java:927)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap (SslHandler.java:1409)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible (SslHandler.java:1247)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode (SslHandler.java:1287)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead (DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead (DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read (AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey (NioEventLoop.java:722)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized (NioEventLoop.java:658)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys (NioEventLoop.java:584)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:496)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run (ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run (FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am using java 8 maven version 3.8.5, my pom is using:

```
         <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.20.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <azure.functions.java.library.version>2.1.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>

   <dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated

Comment: are you behind a company proxy?

Comment: No I am not behind company proxy.